# C# "condition coalescing" operator

Tags: c#, operators

Is there any special expression or some kind or syntactic sugar built in in C# that would allow one to change a variable's value or leave it alone depending on condition?
I mean something that would do following:

```
str = (condition) ? "modifiedString" : str;
```

or

```
if (condition) str = "modifiedString";
```

But with simplicity of null coalescing operator. Something like

```
str = (condition) ?? "modifiedString"
```

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with `if (condition) str = "modifiedString";`?

Comment: It's OK, I guess. But what was wrong with checking against null so that they introduced "??" operator?

Comment: @PaulKyrejto: The possibility to use it as an expression, e.g. in `var someOTHERstring = myString ?? "valueInsteadOfNull"` or `someMethod(myString ?? "valueInsteadOfNull")`.

Comment: Checking against null was (1) very common, and (2) involved repeating the variable name twice (once inside the condition, once outside), so they thought it warranted a new syntax.

Comment: Well probably I'm making things up and there's really no need for it. Thanx anyway

Comment: Check out [every feature starts with -100 point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) to understand general approach to new features.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if(condition)
   str = "modified"
```

Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: I aware of that. See above. Just wondering if any alternatives present.